# Any good resource on Android UI styling

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to learn to make beautiful Android apps.

The things I want to know more about are:

```
- how to create drawables (with / without states)
- apply borders, change backgrounds
- styling / customising action bar
```

The resources on developer.android are sparse, I need something in-depth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `developer.android` is enough for UI styling if you have gone through all the tutorials thoroughly, however you can have a look at the following links, very informative for UI styling :

[Link 1](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html)

[Link 2](http://developers.janrain.com/how-to/mobile-apps/sdk/social-login/android/custom-ui-for-android/#)